# Dapper - extracting single value already stored in local variable

Tags: c#, dapper

I am using Dapper with a stored procedure.

```
public List<Sifrarnik> ChangeOpisText(string opis)
        {
            using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Cloud"].ConnectionString))
            {
                if (db.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    db.Open();
                }

                var response = db.Query<Sifrarnik>("dbo.spChangeOpisText @opis",
                    new
                    {
                        opis = opis

                    }).ToList();
                return response;
            }
        }
```

I pass a single variable to the query and retrieve a single column/row from a database. This result is stored in the response variable.

But I don't **know how to access the value and place it in a textbox.** Any clues?

`textbox1.Text = ?`

For instance.. doing it for a combobox would be:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = response;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "column-name";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "column-name";
```

When I check the type of the variable in prints List from the Data model I use for Dapper.

Comment: FYI you don't need the `State` check and call to open the connection.  Dapper's `Query` method will do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to retrieve a single row, why are you returning a list? Just return a single instance of `Sifrarnik`.

You can get the instance from the returned enumerable by using [`Single()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.single?view=netframework-4.8).

```
public Sifrarnik ChangeOpisText(string opis)
{
    using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Cloud"].ConnectionString))
    {
        if (db.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            db.Open();
        }

        var response = db.Query<Sifrarnik>
        (
            "dbo.spChangeOpisText @opis",
            new
            {
                opis = opis
            }
        )
        .Single();
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `Cannot implicitly convert type 'erp.Sifrarnik' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<erp.Sifrarnik>` like this.

Comment: There is no `List` anywhere in my code example. So it must be something in your code. Are you trying to store the result of `ChangeOpisText()` in a list?

Comment: I have a class called Sifrarnik which maps a table in my database. Based on what I read for Dapper from the documentation.. Dapper will map the response to a class, which is a list that looks like this: `namespace erp
{
    public class Sifrarnik
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string prefiks { get; set; }
        public string opis { get; set; }

    }
}`

Comment: You didn't answer my question. My code contains no declaration of `System.Collections.Generic.List<erp.Sifrarnik>` anywhere, so it must be yours. Do you want to work with a single instance or a list? Make up your mind be consistent about it.

Comment: So the issue here is that you do not know how to read the properties from the single object instance in the list? Does that sum it up?